# Overlaying a bitmap over a white background using a resize method

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap

I have a method that takes in a value called `sourceBMP`, `width`, and `height`, and resizes the image according to those specification.

The `result` variable is the specified dimensions of the new BMP. What this method does is it takes the `sourceBMP`, renders it on the points `0, 0`, and interpolates it using the `NearestNeighbor` (since these are pixels that are being interpolated, `NearestNeighbor` was the best choice)  to the desired width and height.

```
    private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width, height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

With that said - how do I change it so I overlay this graph over a white background instead (so I can add x and y axis labels onto the graph)? [image] Trying to change the parameters myself, like specifying the starting point in a position higher than `0, 0` (like `result.Width/6` )only made the image go off the screen.

EDIT: For example:

```
    private Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width + (width/3), height + (height/3));
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, width / 6, height / 6, width + (width / 3), height + (height / 3));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The above code pushes the graph off-screen instead of fitting inside the dimensions.

Comment: This is a basic mistake, you are resizing the bitmap.  Use g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, width / 6, height / 6, width, height);

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you so much. Mind if you put it as an answer so I can check it as answer?

Comment: I cannot think of a way this is ever going to be helpful to anybody else.  It was just a simple mistake with a trivial workaround.  Please delete your question.

Comment: I'm not deleting it. I've tried Googling this question for few times and checking the MSDN forums before asking it. If it helped me, I can't think of why it won't help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(width + (width/3), height + (height/3));
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
            g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, width / 6, height / 6, width, height);
        }
        return result;
    }
```